# Add message to Smali file OR convert Java to Smali

Tags: java, android, dex, smali

Hi I want to add a messsage into this Smali file but I dont understad how its works. I cant convert my Java code to Smali.

I want to show my V2 variable. I Try this: 
invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

But doesnt work... The app crashes when start. Thanks you, I apreciate any help!

The Entery code:

```
.class public final Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;


# annotations
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/EnclosingClass;
    value = Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a;
.end annotation

.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/InnerClass;
    accessFlags = 0x9
    name = "a"
.end annotation


# instance fields
.field public a:B

.field public b:B

.field public c:[B


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method public constructor <init>(BB[B)V
    .locals 0

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    iput-byte p1, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->a:B

    iput-byte p2, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->b:B

    iput-object p3, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->c:[B

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public final toString()Ljava/lang/String;
    .locals 3

    new-instance v0, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-direct {v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>()V

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v2, "Sector: "

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    iget-byte v2, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->a:B

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v1, "line.separator"

    invoke-static {v1}, Ljava/lang/System;->getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v2, "Key Type: "

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    iget-byte v2, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->b:B

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v1, "line.separator"

    invoke-static {v1}, Ljava/lang/System;->getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    new-instance v1, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v2, "Key: "

    invoke-direct {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/sube/subemobileclient/b/b/b/b/b/a$a;->c:[B

    invoke-static {v2}, Ljava/util/Arrays;->toString([B)Ljava/lang/String;





    **HEREHEREHERE**  So message to display = "Key: ...." 




    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    const-string v1, "line.separator"

    invoke-static {v1}, Ljava/lang/System;->getProperty(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

.end method
```

JAVA

```
   public final String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder("Sector: ");
        stringBuilder2.append(this.f892a);
        stringBuilder.append(stringBuilder2.toString());
        stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder("Key Type: ");
        stringBuilder2.append(this.f893b);
        stringBuilder.append(stringBuilder2.toString());
        stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder("Key: ");
        stringBuilder2.append(Arrays.toString(this.f894c));
        stringBuilder.append(stringBuilder2.toString());
        stringBuilder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Which `v2` register?

Comment: Sorry I missed. I enter an indication in the code, go to the end. 3 lines after "const-string v2," Key: "".

Comment: Trying to Toast `v2` from that point will result in an error. Are you sure you don't mean to Toast `v1` (your StringBuilder) after calling `toString()` on it?

Comment: You also can't show Toasts without a Context, which that class doesn't have.

Comment: Where should Trying to Toast be? In my code I have 4 variables that contain: "Sector", "Key Type" and "Key". Then each one is completed with more text. I want to show my variable "Key" in a message

Comment: You want to literally just toast "Key: "?

Comment: No, in the next 3 lines after "Key: " more information is added to this variable. I want Toast this variable with all the information .. I am going to add my Java code to the post.

Comment: So you want to Toast `stringBuilder2`? No matter what, though, you still can't Toast without a Context Object, which you don't have.

Comment: Yes I want to Toast stringBuilder2. Ok I try to add Context Object. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Smali code from Java just like from any Android App. Therefore you can simply write a very small Android app that contains your code.

Create a simple app in AndroidStudio that contains the code. Build the app and the decompile the apk file using `apktool` and you have your Java code converted to Smali code.

The easiest way should be to create a new function that can then be injected into the existing Smali code and called from an existing function.

Or the same way but using some shortcuts:

.java --> .class --> dex -> smali

Compile Java to a class file (AFAIR you have to use Java 7 as target). Then convert the code to a dex file using `dx` (java -jar `dx.jar`) tool from Android SDK. And in the end decompile it with `apktool`.